# Custom Windows Authentication Login Form

Tags: 2007, windows-authentication

When a user on a non-company asset (i.e. not connected to the domain) logs on to our SharePoint site, they are presented with a default windows popup dialog.  We would like to remove this dialog and provide a log in form on our top-level site (which is set for anonymous access).

Is it possible to log a user in programmatically under Windows Authentication?  How would I do this?

**Note:** The site **MUST** be set for Windows Authentication, so Forms Authentication with the ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider won't work.

---

A little more context:  The users will be connected to the internal network, but using their own computers (like students that connect to a school network), so VPNs are unnecessary.  We are using **MOSS 2007**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Microsoft Threat Management Gateway 2010 can do this. See answers to [this related question](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/15654/best-authentication-method-for-accessing-sharepoint-web-from-the-internet).

Answer (score 0):

very do-able and not very difficult :-)

Read here: http://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2010/10/18/sharepoint-2010-claims-authentication-custom-login-form-part-3-developing-a-custom-login-form/

The following two lines of code should do the job:

```
SecurityToken tk = SPSecurityContext.SecurityTokenForFormsAuthentication(
new Uri(SPContext.Current.Web.Url), "ADProvider", null,Username.Text, Password.Text);

if (tk != null)
    {
        SPFederationAuthenticationModule fam = SPFederationAuthenticationModule.Current;
        fam.SetPrincipalAndWriteSessionToken(tk);
    }
```

Comment: I'm using MOSS 2007, there doesn't appear to be a `SPSecurityContext` class available for 2007.

Comment: Hi There. Sorry for not responding in a loooong time. So basically, you want to also use your normal users with AD Auth, and some other users with Anonymous? Why not just extend the web application and have the second web app use Anonymous?

Comment: We ended up scrapping this project, so its irrelevant now.  The 3rd party product we were using required Windows authentication (it tied it self in with FIM).  We wanted to customize the login screen so users would be presented with a login form on a page, instead of the generic windows login popup prompt (our users would be coming in from outside the domain, so wouldn't auth automatically).  My idea was to create a login page and allow anonymous access for that, then redirect to the site requiring auth after login.